# SelectableText.rich in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to make 3 texts that are copyable and I want to choose SelectableText.rich.
So you can choose what you want to copy.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text ("Better Hashtag"), backgroundColor: Colors.red),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
           SelectableText.rich(Textspan (

           )
           );
        ],
      ),
    );

  }
}
```

I get an error by SelectableText.rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error are you getting?

Have you added the `flutter_selectedtext` dependency to your `pubspec.yaml` file?

```dart
flutter_selectext: ^0.1.1
```

More info: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_selectext

You also have a syntax problem:

```dart
body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
           SelectableText.rich(Textspan (

           )
           );     // <----- remove this semi-colon, as you are still
                  //        in the list of children of the Column widget.
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: I have already added and imported flutter_selectable. I also removed the semi-colon but there ist the same error. It says "The method 'rich' isn't defined for the class 'SelectableText'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'rich'." and the same for Textspan.

Answer (score 0):

SelectableText is included in Flutter 1.9 release. So if you are using Flutter 1.9 or above, you don't need to add any dependency to your pubspec.yaml file, can just use it directly.

If you are not sure about the syntax, check out this example: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText-class.html#material.SelectableText.2

If you are using an older version of Flutter and getting the error, run flutter upgrade. Once complete it should work. As of the date of this response, Flutter stable channel is on 1.9.1. So no matter which channel you are using, as soon as you upgrade Flutter, you should have SelectableText.rich ready to use without having to add any dependency to your pubspec.yaml file.